# Surface pro 3 keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard

having problems with keyboard on surface pro 3 not working, have tried volume key up and start button at same time, then trusted platform module opens and keyboard is working , when I exit TPM and start surface keyboard no longer works?

Comment: Have you tried a wired USB keyboard? Does that work?

Comment: No I have not do not have one

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately a known issue with Surface Pro 3 keyboards. Sometimes it was software, other times it was a broken ribbon cable.

The broken ribbon cable happens when the keyboard is flipped behind. Not sure why they didn't test this more, but it'll break it after about the 50th time doing it.

For the software issue, Microsoft release a firmware fix for it some time ago, but you probably already have it installed if you've kept up with your updates.

Check out this website for the [Surface Pro 3 Firmware](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=38826) files.

The ones you want to download are...

> SurfacePro3_Win10_18362_1902002_0.msi

> Surface Firmware Tool.msi

> Surface Pro 3 KB2978002.zip

And if all else fails, you can do a full restore of the OS.  I suggest a clean install, as detailed in the [link here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/creating-and-using-a-usb-recovery-drive-for-surface-677852e2-ed34-45cb-40ef-398fc7d62c07).